# Php form data won't insert data on my PhpMyAdmin database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been trying to resolve this but i can't see the error. please help me. This is my code so far. What should i do? i checked every detail but cant find it. when i click the button, there's no error and it will return in the reservation.php page. I also have a "res_id" in my database which is auto increment. how should i include it in the insert statement?

Php code:

```
<?

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db("hoteldb",$hoteldb) or die("no db found");

if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){
    $fname= $_POST['fname'];
    $lname= $_POST['lname'];
    $contact= $_POST['contact'];
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $address= $_POST['address'];
    $checkin= $_POST['checkin'];
    $checkout= $_POST['checkout'];

    $query="INSERT INTO reservation(fname,lname,contact,username,password,email,address,checkin,checkout)
    VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$contact','$username','$password','$email','$address','$checkin','$checkout')";

    mysql_query($query,$conn);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Html code:

```
 <form action="reservation.php" method="post">
                        <div>
                            <label>Title:</label>
                            <select name="title">
                                <option value="ms">Ms.</option>
                                <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
                                <option value="mrs">Mrs.</option>
                                </select>    

                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="fname">
                        </div> 
                        <div>
                           <label>Last Name:</label>
                           <input type="text" name="lname">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Phone Number:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="contact">
                         </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" >
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" >
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <label>Email Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" >
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <h5>Address</h5>
                            <div >
                                <label>Full Address:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="address" >
                            </div>
                        <hr>
                        <h5>Date</h5>
                        <div >
                            <legend>Check-in</legend> 
                            <input type="date" name="checkin"> 

                            <legend>Checkout </legend> 
                            <input type="date" name="checkout">
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" name="confirm">
                    </form>
```

or is it because of the date picker? if so, can you please teach me how to use the date picker? its my first time using it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Don't mix `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*`. And you need to read up on sql injection.

Comment: @jeroen added letter "i" to my mysql_query but its still not inserting data to the database. i'll edit the code for sql injection after I solved this issue. thank you.

Comment: If any value has a `'` in it, the query will break, besides the SQLi issue, why are you not debugging it with [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), there are plenty of tutorials on the interwebs.

Comment: You should start with the manual.

Comment: You've started on a very wrong foot. You should learn a few things, before start coding. This is a good place to start: http://www.phptherightway.com

Comment: Try to echo SQL Statement you will get query and try to run that query in phpMyadmin. if your query is wrong then try to pass variables carefully..

Answer (score 0):

try to get error description: (add after $query's definition)

```
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on PHP errors to not get just an empty page.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

```
mysql_query($query, $conn);
```

this should be

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

> I also have a "res_id" in my database which is auto increment. how should i include it in the insert statement?

Since it's set to "auto increment", you dont need to do anything with it

Also, try looking at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), it's safer and takes less code to use.

Answer (score 0):

The error in Mysqli_select_db statement.

You need correct your statement.

```
mysqli_select_db("hoteldb",$hoteldb) or die("no db found");
```

insted of this

```
mysqli_select_db($conn,"hoteldb") or die("no db found");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to the database you use mysql, after this you are trying to insert data using mysqli_query, it is impossible. You have to replace

```
mysql_query($query,$conn);
```

with

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

so your php will look like this

```
<?

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db("hoteldb",$hoteldb) or die("no db found");

if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){
    $fname= $_POST['fname'];
    $lname= $_POST['lname'];
    $contact= $_POST['contact'];
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $address= $_POST['address'];
    $checkin= $_POST['checkin'];
    $checkout= $_POST['checkout'];

    $query="INSERT INTO reservation(fname,lname,contact,username,password,email,address,checkin,checkout)
    VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$contact','$username','$password','$email','$address','$checkin','$checkout')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

This is main problem.

You can use this templates any time u need insert something in your database

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

If u want to use mysqli go to
**Example (MySQLi Procedural)** part

But I would recommend to use PDO;